# may just have yet to upload or may just have not uploaded yet

Tags: grammar

I am trying to decide between

"may just have yet to upload" or "may just have not yet uploaded"

Is one preferable to another technically (not just opinion).

Comment: could you provide some context?

Comment: It's for a paper I'm writing. I guess I was asking if there was any grammatical reason for preferring one over the other

Comment: I meant could you provide the surrounding sentences, to give that some context?  That way we can better understand if there's a better way to write it.

Comment: The _have yet to `VP`_ idiom has very restricted syntax. If you're not familiar with it, don't use it.

Comment: have I misused it?

Comment: @Sam: Effectively, yes. Compare *"Your letter may have yet to arrive"* (at the very least, unusual and ungainly) with *"Your letter may not yet have arrived"* (normal English).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither is preferable, to be honest.

Simply, simplify, simplify. I suggest either

> "It may have yet to upload."

Or,

> "It may not have uploaded yet."

Sentence one sounds a bit hoity-toity. Sentence two sounds less snooty and would likely be more common in everyday parlance. The choice is yours.

Comment: I can see that you might want to use upload intransitively sometimes, but surely anything that can be uploaded can't carry out the action of uploading -- a person or automated system uploads data. So I would go for the passive, but still drop the "just" - "it may have yet to be uploaded" or better "it may not have been uploaded yet"

Comment: @ChrisH: Good point. You may want to forgive me, as I'm computer-lingo challenged; but hey, I'm learning!

Comment: No problem at all, it's just my opinion.  You've got the right point and it's more than possible I'm being old-fashioned anyway.